# Css .gif flicker trouble shooting?

Tags: html, css

Question? what causes flicker on a hover over image? If the image was .jpg would it do the same thing? Are there any preventive measures, the will prevent this preload page etc
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are talking about having a different background-img url for the hover state than the non-hover state? If so my preferred solution is using a sprite that contains both the static and hover states in the same image and simply sliding the image up / down using background-position. This prevents waiting on image load when hovering, and shouldn't have any flickering.

Here's a simple example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Is there a way to preload the webpage... I would have to change a lot of buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure about preloading the whole page, but you could preload the required images using all sorts of various techniques. Here's a simple search result that should cover what you need: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/